# 1&1 virtual host, no websites will load.

Tags: web-hosting, vps, plesk

I have a vps with 1&1 with paarallels plesk installed and have used it to host several websites for 2-3 years.

Yesterday I made an update to mysite and it was working when I exited the website lastnight.

This morning I try access my website but the page will not load and I receive a brower error saying - The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

It has been like this for at least 4 hours. I have logged into my VPS in 1&1 but cannot see anything which would indicate whether there is a server problem or not.

I have contacted 1&1 asking for support in the past but on occasions they have taken 2-3 days to reply.

How can I find out if the problem is with 1&1/my VPS or with one of the websites I have hosted on the VPS?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: have you tried loading the website from a different machine?

Comment: Hi Aakash, yeah, 2 different machines, different internet connections, different broswers.

Comment: I've found that the quickest way to get 1&1 support is actually if you contact them through Twitter.

Comment: why would you be with any company that takes 2 - 3 days for support on a VPS?